# IOS - Generating PDF from UIwebview in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I am trying to generate a PDF report from a `UIWebView`. Using `Graphics Contexts` I can get the images of screen frame and draw it in PDF.

*Problems in curent method are,*
Images are blurred (bad quality)
So the report pdf is not readable.

How can I get a high quality images of a screen frame? Or is there any other better solutions for my problem?

P.S. Report includes multiple background colors and images, I think it is hard to directly draw them in PDF.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. currently the images is good, but PDF is blured

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, webview.bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[webview.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Have you tried like this?

Comment: Thank 4 da reply.. my web view's scroll height is 1500.. so I have to capture the screen part by part and join.

Comment: then take the x,y coordinates which you wants as frame as separate uiview then rendering it as pdf